# Raspberry Pi not booting up and sd card splitting

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

I am using a raspian stretch and tried to write the image onto a SD card. Whenever the writing process is completed a partition 4gb is formed and the windows prompts me to format it. I am using a 16gb class 10 uhs san disk SD card. The card when inserted into the raspberry pi it does not boots up. I used softwares like etcher,Win32disk Imager,Rufus all with the same results.
I tried the sd card on both Raspberry pi Zero as well As raspberry pi 3 model b.....What to do now..?

Comment: you're not formatting the partition, are you?

Comment: what does happen when you boot up? what pattern of flashes do you observer on the activity led

Comment: A screenshot/photo would be helpful. Sound like your downloaded image is corrupted.

Comment: The Problem is solved it was my HDMI cable it worked fine  with  other displays but not with raspberry pi zero....Changing it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the instructions in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md it should work in the Pi.

You should verify the SHA-256 checksum BEFORE copying.

Ignore anything Windows says - it can't (actually won't - it could) read Linux partitions.

Comment: Problem solved. MY HDMI cable was not supported by the Pi.ThankYou @Milliways